# if props are empty fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When you load the page, data will be fetched and displayed. When you press on the button, you get linked to the page with the single data from the array. So you go to /property/10. The problem is, when you go to /property/9 without clicking the button, you will get an error because props are empty. I'm sending the props with the button click.

Im trying to check if the props are empty, fetch the data from the api.

```
<Link to={{
    pathname: `/property/${a.id}`,
    state: {
        id: a.id,
        title: a.title,
        text: a.text,
        address: a.address,
        rooms: a.rooms,
        surface: a.surface,
        baths: a.baths,
        price: a.price,
        typeProperty: a.typeProperty,
        date: a.date,
        files: a.files
    }
}}>
    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-details text float-right">
        Details
    </button>
</Link>
```

On the other page I have this:

```
getProperty = () => {
    fetch(`/api/advertentie/${this.props.match.params.id}`, {
        method: "GET"
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
        this.props.location.state = result
        console.log(this.props.location.state) // I get the correct data
    })
}

render() {
    if (!this.props.location.state) {
        this.getProperty()
    }
    console.log(this.props.location.state) // gives me undefined
    const { id, title, text, address, rooms, surface, baths, price, typeProperty, date, files } = 
    this.props.location.state // id not found because it is undefined
}
```

The problem is this.props.location.state is still empty after fetching in the render

Comment: This a synchronisation issue. Simply the log inside the `render` is being executed before the fetch in the `getProperty` finishes.

Comment: One way to handle this is to `await` for the fetch call to finish, just make sure you wrap the function as `async`.

Comment: Where should I put await?